# Using regular expression to delete words in between specific words

Tags: python, nlp, data-cleaning, python-re

My data contains something like these:

```
→ muching :酋長在這個距離的時候，北部山區都超過大豪雨標準了

推aitt :台東恆春間登陸不代表北台不會有強風.

→ teras: 7／7
```

I want my data to look like these:

```
酋長在這個距離的時候，北部山區都超過大豪雨標準了

台東恆春間登陸不代表北台不會有強風.

 7／7
```

I already tried some regex `re.sub(r'^推:$', '', x)` but I'm pretty sure this way is wrong.

does regex work with Chinese characters or → symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, it will remove everything that starts in a line before the `:` and `→` does work with Chinese characters:

```
import re

txt = """
→ muching :酋長在這個距離的時候，北部山區都超過大豪雨標準了

推aitt :台東恆春間登陸不代表北台不會有強風.

→ teras: 7／7

"""

pattern = r'^.*:'
parsed_txt = re.sub(pattern, '', txt, flags=re.MULTILINE)

print(parsed_txt)
>>>"
酋長在這個距離的時候，北部山區都超過大豪雨標準了

台東恆春間登陸不代表北台不會有強風.

 7／7"
```

Comment: thank you for the answer it mostly works for me. but for some lines, too much text was cut because there were `:` near the end. is there a way to limit `:` only for the first appearance?

Comment: u can specify a certain format before the `:`, for example is it always going to be arrow+word+: or word+space+: at the begining of the sentence?

Comment: actually, my data are not always in the format. but I tried `r'^.*?:'` instead and it works quite well (although I lose some of the text which are not in the format and happens to have `:`) is there a better to deal with this, but I'm also fine with the result now too.